# Getting empty string from HTML input event in Firefox

Tags: html, reactjs, google-chrome, firefox

Selected option not reflecting. I have a drop-down which is `controlled` input. Whenever any option is chosen then getting empty string from `event.target.value` = `<empty string>`

This issue not occurs in **Google Chrome**. Everything working fine as expected but not in **Firefox**.

Here is my code:

```
<select
    id="location"
    required
    name="location_id"
    className="form-control form-control-sm"
    value={item.location_id} // <-- state data
    onChange={(e) => {
      setVariantsLocations(
         e,
         product.bundle_variant_id,
         bv.sku,
         item.id
         );
     }}>
      <option value="">--Select--</option>
      {bv.locations?.map((loc) => {
             return (
               <option
                  value={loc?.id}
                  disabled={loc.quantity === 0}>
                     {loc?.code} [Q: {loc.quantity}]
               </option>
              );
             })
       }
</select>
```

```
setVariantsLocations = (e, parentSku, childSku, item_id) => {
    console.log(e.target.value) // <empty string>
}
```

Comment: What version of React are you using? What is logged via `console.log(JSON.stringify(e.target.value))`? Have you tried logging the event `e` directly in the anonymous callback handler *before* it's passed to `setVariantsLocations`? Think you could create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue that we can inspect and debug live?

Comment: React `v16.14.0`  & Getting `''` from `console.log(JSON.stringify(e.target.value))`

Comment: Thanks. Can you try making a codesandbox then?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, confirm that your event handler is being called at all, rather than the target value being empty - the easiest way being to change your `console.log` to:

```
console.log(`Event: '${e.currentTarget.value}'`)
```

I'm thinking that because you've got a controlled component, your logic for setting the `value` of the `select` is somehow not right, and thus you're not "completing the circle" and getting the change into the DOM. Try simplifying it down to a simple string being controlled by a `useState()` and see if it helps, and don't "close over" the arguments to `setVariantsLocations`; e.g.:

```
const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(undefined); 

...

  const setVariantsLocations = (e) => {
    console.log(`Event: '${e.target.value}'`);
    setSelectedId(e.target.value);
  };

...

<select
  id="location"
  required
  name="location_id"
  className="form-control form-control-sm"
  value={selectedId} // <-- state data
  onChange={setVariantsLocations}
>
```

Now you've got just-about the simplest controlled component you can get. If that is working in all browsers, start adding back in the complexity and see where it starts to go wrong.